# Using definite integral to find the limit.

Tags: calculus, limits, definite-integrals, solution-verification, riemann-sum

I would like someone to verify this exercise for me. Please.

Find the following limit:

$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\left(\dfrac{1}{n+1}+\dfrac{1}{n+2}+...+\dfrac{1}{3n}\right)$

$=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\left(\dfrac{1}{n+1}+\dfrac{1}{n+2}+...+\dfrac{1}{n+2n}\right)$

$=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2n} \dfrac{1}{n+k}$

$=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2n} \dfrac{1}{n\left(1+\frac{k}{n}\right)}$

$=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2n}\left(\dfrac{1}{1+\frac{k}{n}}\cdot\dfrac{1}{n}\right)$

$=\displaystyle\int_{1+0}^{1+2} \frac{1}{x} \,dx$

$=\displaystyle\int_{1}^{3} \frac{1}{x} \,dx$

$=\big[\ln|x|\big] _{1}^3$

$=\ln|3|-\ln|1|$

$=\ln(3)-\ln(1)$

$=\ln(3)$

Comment: Check your bounds of integration again: $k$ ranges from $1$ to $2n$, not $1$ to $n$.

Comment: @lc2r43 but why? is 3 the upper limit?

Answer (score 4):

Lastly, use $\;k/n\rightarrow x,\;\;1/n \to dx\;,\;$ then
$$L=\int_{0}^{2} \frac{dx}{1+x}=\ln(1+x)\big|_{0}^{2}=\ln 3\;.$$

Edit: the lower limit is $x_l=1/n, x_u=2n/n$, when $n$ is large ($\infty$} these are 0 and 2

Comment: how do I know the limits of integrations are 0 and 2?

Comment: You may see my edit now.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}S_n&=\dfrac{1}{n+1}+\dfrac{1}{n+2}+...+\dfrac{1}{3n}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{1}{n+k}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n+k}+\underbrace{\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{1}{n+k}}_{l=k-n}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n+k}+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2n+l}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{n+k}+\frac{1}{2n+k}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{1+\frac{k}{n}}+\frac{1}{2+\frac{k}{n}}\right)\\
\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align}\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}S_n&=\int_0^1 \left(\frac{1}{1+x}+\frac{1}{2+x}\right)dx\\
&=\Big[\ln(1+x)+\ln(2+x)\Big]_0^1\\
&=\ln 2+\ln 3-0-\ln 2\\
&=\boxed{\ln 3}
\end{align}